# Sumproduct to with duplicate column headers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with inputs where each group represents multiple inputs values that correspond to that groups respective premium ( script for test data below)

Each value in that row is a key to a table which contains factors for multiple perils (e.g fire, Water Weather).

What I want to do is create a premium column which is the sum product of each perils factors. Example output in premium_output_df.

input_df is an example of what my start data looks like albeit much smaller and with less column fields.

amount_of_insurance_df is a representation of the table which contains the peril factors with each groups corresponding Amount of Insurance value.

territory df is a representation of the table which contains the peril territory factors.

To run through an example, the Premium for group 1 will be the sum product of the perils. (0.1*0.94)+(0.2*0.3)=0.154=Total Premium group1

To give you an idea of the process I used to collect the data.

Each column in input_df represents a table that gets merged to come collect the factors for each peril, please see below for an example of a merge being done for the actual ( not raw) data set.

```
amount_of_insurance=pd.merge(data_for_rater["Enter Amount of Insurance"],
                             df['Amount of Insurance'],
                             how='left', 
                             left_on='Enter Amount of Insurance' , 
                             right_on='Amount Of Insurance')
```

My current method is the following:

```
concat_df=pd.concat([amount_of_insurance_df,data_territory],axis=1,sort=False)

prod_concat=concat_df.groupby(level=0,axis=1).prod()
```

Then Just add the two columns, Thoughts on a better way to proceed?

Test Data

```
    input_data={'Group':[1,2,3,4,5],'Amount of Insurance':[28000,28000,28000,28000,28000],'Territory':[701,702,703,704,705]}

data_amount_of_insurance={'Amount of Insurance':[28000,28000,28000,28000,28000],'Fire':[.10,.20,.30,.40,.50],'Water Weather':[.20,.30,.40,.50,.60]}

data_territory={'Territory':[701,702,703,704,705],'Fire':[.94,.95,.96,.97,.98],'Water Weather':[.30,.40,.50,.60,.70]}

    input_df=pd.DataFrame(input_data)

    amount_of_insurance_df=pd.DataFrame(data_amount_of_insurance)

    territory_df=pd.DataFrame(data_territory)

    premium_output_data={'Group':[1,2,3,4,5],'Amount of Insurance':[28000,28000,28000,28000,28000],'Territory':[701,702,703,704,705],'Fire Premium':[0.094,0.19,0.288,0.388,0.49],'Water Weather Premium':[0.06,0.12,0.2,0.3,0.42],'Total Premium':[0.154,0.31,0.488,0.688,0.91]}
    premium_output_df=pd.DataFrame(premium_output_data)
```

Comment: amount_of_insurance_df doesn't have a key to tie to the other tables, are you just assuming that index matches?

Comment: Amount_of_insurance_df is a representation of the output once the merge occurs. Please see the merge example up top.

Comment: I think what you've done here works.  Just add `prod_concat['Premium'] = prod_concat['Fire'] + prod_concat['Water Weather']`

Comment: The part i'm a bit confused at is since I have around 47 tables that are similar to Amount_of_insurance_df, and territory_df, would I just pass all the data frames to a list, and perform the concatenation?